# Tracking the status of project-excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to track the status of a project: I have 4 columns each with date format.  A status column which would show "OVERDUE" if the date in column A is over 12 days. "CURRENT" if less than 12 days. However, if a date is entered in column D the status would show "COMPLETE".

I am very new at this, 
thanks for any help!

Comment: How will dates be entered in column D?

Comment: they will be in the dd-mmm-yy format.

Comment: Can you use VBA, or just formula?

Comment: No VBA, Just formula.

Comment: THIS is what I have so far, and works, but adding "COMPLETE" Is confusing me.:

Comment: =IF(TODAY()-(B4)<10,"CURRENT","OVDUE")

Comment: When I change the date in column A, it doesn't change from CURRENT to OVERDUE.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(D1="",
IF(A1-NOW>12,"OVERDUE","CURRENT"),
IF(CELL("Format",D1)="D1","COMPLETE",
IF(A1-NOW>12,"OVERDUE","CURRENT"))
```

Let me know if you want some indicator for whether a value is entered in D and is not in the correct format.